# Returning an element from a list in java

Tags: java, list, return

Can you tell me what are the advantages (if there is any advantage) of using `getTheLastElement2()` instead of `getTheLastElement()`? I mean why is it necessary to create the reference `obj` when it is easier just to return the result?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    List list;

    Test(ArrayList list){
        this.list = list;
    }

    public Object getTheLastElement(){
        if (list.isEmpty())
            return null;
        else
            return list.get(list.size()-1);
    }

    public Object getTheLastElement2(){
        Object obj;
        if (list.isEmpty())
            obj = null;
        else
            obj = list.get(list.size()-1);
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: Neither of these works.

Comment: You'll have to return the `size - 1`th element, not just `size`.

Comment: You might also like to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36707/should-a-function-have-only-one-return-statement which discusses the pros and cons of having a single exit point vs multiple exit points in a function. In your code example I would suggest that `getTheLastElement()` is more readable, and would be even more so without the `else` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between these two implementations: the `obj` reference will probably be optimized away.

You do get a slight advantage when debugging the code, because you can set breakpoint on the `return` statement of `getTheLastElement2`, and know that it is always going to be hit. This is in contrast with `getTheLastElement`, where you would need two breakpoints to examine the return value.

Note that `else` in the first example is redundant:

```
public Object getTheLastElement(){
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    return list.get(list.size()-1);
}
```

You could further shrink this to a single ternary expression:

```
public Object getTheLastElement(){
    return !list.isEmpty() ? list.get(list.size()-1) : null;
}
```

Comment: Would that else influence the execution time?

Comment: @rEx No, it is redundant, and is going to be eliminated by the compiler. In terms of execution speed these all are equal.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no advantage. Also, you should return `list.get(list.size()-1)`